# Add new row and copy same format and formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I have to add new row below the last row for instance by clicking a command button. The new row should have same formatting and formula as the other rows above.
Above row has conditional formatting, colour, drop down list, data validation, fixed row height and formulas. All these should be copied automatically when new row is created. Worksheet is protected.
Can you please help me what code to write to get the best results.
Also the sheet should allow user to delete selected row.
thanks.

```
Sub Add_row()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ActiveSheet.Range("A13").CurrentRegion.Offset(ActiveSheet.Range("A13").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1).Resize(2).EntireRow.FillDown
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True,  AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This website is not a free code writing service. Please show the code you already have.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have any code as I am still a beginner in VBA. Thats the reason I am asking for some help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO Is not a "Code for Me", "Teach me to Code", or a "Show where to Start" site. It is a place for those with existing code with specific problems to get specific help on overcoming said problems. If you don't know how to code yet, then you'll have to learn it: start by recording the things you want Excel to do for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_HQGHPBYoo Afterwards, have a look at the code and try to understand it. Also, you might want to read this: http://www.homeandlearn.org/ Then you should be able to provide a first solution to the above problem yourself.

Comment: I have added below code and it works perfect. But rows should not copy any text or value from above row. It should be empty for new data. Can you please tell me which code I have to add to make the cells not copy previous text or value.

Comment: Sub Add_row()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
ActiveSheet.Range("A13").CurrentRegion.Offset(ActiveSheet.Range("A13").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1).Resize(2).EntireRow.FillDown
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True _
    , AllowFiltering:=True
    
       
End Sub

Comment: Please never add any code into comments, use the edit button to edit the question and add your code nicely formatted into the question. Code comments are unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`Range.Copy` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").Copy 'example
```

and the [`Range.PasteSpecial` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

There are several [paste types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx). E.g `xlPasteFormats` only pastes formats.